# How to implement MPI_MINLOC in OpenMP?

Tags: c, mpi, openmp, hpc, reduction

How can I compute a global minimum and an index attached to the minimum value in OpenMP using the C language?

Can I obtain a real benefit with few threads?

```
// thread-private result
double mymin = DBL_MAX;
double myloc = SIZE_MAX;

// bottleneck parallel part
#pragma omp for reduction(min:gmin)
for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    if (v[i] < mymin) {
        mymin = v[i];
        gmin = v[i];
        myloc = i;
    }
}

if(gmin == mymin) {
// find global result
  #pragma omp single
  {
     gloc = myloc;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I was confused by your terminology. Perhaps you mean simply how to invoke OpenMP parallelism for an algorithm equivalent to Fortran min_loc or C++ min_element().  Unfortunately, I haven't tested this extensively since the days of gcc7 and Intel C++ 19 (trying lately to get a renewed license for the latter).  In my experience, successful implementation requires an outer parallel loop. My test represents a 2 dimensional grid; if your current algorithm is only a single loop you must partition to nested loops. The outer loop uses a critical section to combine inner results.

Comment: Of course, you first find a suitable simd single thread implementation for your inner loop, In order to benefit from inner simd outer parallel optimization, inner and outer loops would need to have counts on order of 1000.  As you would normally expect, you could approach linear scaling for a small number of threads with omp_places working.  Is my worked example not still present on github?

Comment: there is no "native" minloc reduction operator in OpenMP, but you can define your own (e.g. user-defined reduction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can obtain a benefit for large problems using OpenMP here.  The benefit will be realized when the input is large enough to be memory-bandwidth-limited and multiple threads provide higher memory bandwidth.  This will almost certainly be limited to inputs that do not fit in the last level of cache.

I've included a simple example program on how to do this.  This implementation uses old and widely-available features.  It may be possible to use OpenMP 5.0 user-defined reductions but I doubt it this provides a noticeable benefit in performance and you'll likely find many implementations do not support this feature.

Note that my example program does not time repeated tests nor do any statistics on the timings.  Thus, you should not consider it a highly scientific test.  However, it demonstrates a clear benefit on my dual-core laptop for an array of 100M doubles, as expected.

```
$ make minloc && ./minloc 100000000
icc -O3 -qopenmp -std=c11 minloc.c -o minloc
MINLOC of 100000000 elements with 4 threads
OpenMP: dt=0.076681, gmin=0.000000, gloc=4022958
Sequential: dt=0.157333, gmin=0.000000, gloc=4022958
SUCCESS
```

## Relevant Excerpt

```c
        // thread-private result
        double mymin = DBL_MAX;
        double myloc = SIZE_MAX;

        // bottleneck parallel part
        #pragma omp for
        for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            if (v[i] < mymin) {
                mymin = v[i];
                myloc = i;
            }
        }

        // write thread-private results to shared
        tmin[me] = mymin;
        tloc[me] = myloc;
        #pragma omp barrier

        // find global result
        #pragma omp master
        {
            for (int i=0; i<nt; ++i) {
                if (tmin[i] < gmin) {
                    gmin = tmin[i];
                    gloc = tloc[i];
                }
            }
        }
```

## Complete Example Program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <float.h>

#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t n = (argc > 1) ? atol(argv[1]) : 100;

    double * v = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    if (v==NULL) abort();

    // g = global
    double gmin = DBL_MAX;
    size_t gloc = SIZE_MAX;

    const int mt = omp_get_max_threads();

    printf("MINLOC of %zu elements with %d threads\n", n, mt);

    // t = thread
    double * tmin = malloc(mt * sizeof(double));
    size_t * tloc = malloc(mt * sizeof(size_t));
    if (tmin==NULL || tloc==NULL) abort();

    for (int i=0; i<mt; ++i) {
        tmin[i] = DBL_MAX;
        tloc[i] = SIZE_MAX;
    }

    double dt = 0.0;

    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(n) shared(v, tmin, tloc, gmin, gloc, dt)
    {
        const int me = omp_get_thread_num();
        const int nt = omp_get_num_threads();

        unsigned int seed = (unsigned int)me;
        srand(seed);
        #pragma omp for
        for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            // this is not a _good_ random number generator, but it does not matter for this use case
            double r = (double)rand_r(&seed) / (double)RAND_MAX;
            v[i] = r;
        }

        double t0 = 0.0;

        #pragma omp barrier
        #pragma omp master
        {
            t0 = omp_get_wtime();
        }

        // thread-private result
        double mymin = DBL_MAX;
        double myloc = SIZE_MAX;

        // bottleneck parallel part
        #pragma omp for
        for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            if (v[i] < mymin) {
                mymin = v[i];
                myloc = i;
            }
        }

        // write thread-private results to shared
        tmin[me] = mymin;
        tloc[me] = myloc;
        #pragma omp barrier

        // find global result
        #pragma omp master
        {
            for (int i=0; i<nt; ++i) {
                if (tmin[i] < gmin) {
                    gmin = tmin[i];
                    gloc = tloc[i];
                }
            }
        }

        #pragma omp barrier
        #pragma omp master
        {
            double t1 = omp_get_wtime();
            dt = t1 - t0;
        }

#if 0
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            printf("%d: mymin=%f, myloc=%zu\n", me, mymin, myloc);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
#endif
    }

    printf("OpenMP: dt=%f, gmin=%f, gloc=%zu\n", dt, gmin, gloc);
    fflush(stdout);

    // sequential reference timing
    {
        double t0 = omp_get_wtime();

        double mymin = DBL_MAX;
        double myloc = SIZE_MAX;

        for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            if (v[i] < mymin) {
                mymin = v[i];
                myloc = i;
            }
        }

        gmin = mymin;
        gloc = myloc;

        double t1 = omp_get_wtime();
        dt = t1 - t0;
    }

    printf("Sequential: dt=%f, gmin=%f, gloc=%zu\n", dt, gmin, gloc);
    fflush(stdout);

    // debug printing for toy inputs
    if (n<100) {
        for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            printf("v[%zu]=%f\n", i , v[i]);
        }
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    free(v);

    printf("SUCCESS\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the event anyone wants a GitHub version of this, it is https://github.com/jeffhammond/HPCInfo/blob/master/openmp/minloc.c.  I am happy to accept pull requests if there are suggested improvements.

Comment: Can I use ```tmin[me]``` and ```tloc[me]``` directly instead ```my_min``` and ```my_loc``` inside the ```for``` (bottleneck)?

Comment: You don't want to do that because those arrays are not padded to not share cache lines so updating the tmin/tloc arrays in a loop generates unnecessary coherence traffic.  For example, thread 0 and thread 1 will update the first and second 8 bytes of a cache line repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you, I have another question: what happens if i add ```reduction(min: gmin)``` in the ```#prama omp for``` (bottleneck) as I did above?

Comment: I think that works and it may be faster due to less synchronization, although I am not sure one will notice the difference.